# Enabling code coverage in RunTest Activity of Custom build template

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, code-coverage

I have a  custom update template where I have RunTest activity in the sequence.I am able to run the tests. I do not have default advance test settings in the template. I have to enable code coverage in the RunTest activity. How can we enable the Code coverage for the RunTest activity. Does adding the run settings file enable the code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

No, adding the run settings file is not essential to enable code coverage. Advanced code coverage settings are specified in a .runsettings file. This is **the configuration file** used by unit testing tools.

> If you want the test run to gather and publish code coverage data, set
>   **Options** to **Enable Code Coverage**.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the **Custom** option to specify a
>   .runsettings file. For more information, see [Customizing Code
>   Coverage Analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/jj159530(v=vs.120).aspx).

You can also enable code coverage with below steps :

1.Go to **Process--Test--Automated tests--Test source** in build definition.

2.Now in **Test source** row, click the button with **"...".**

3.Under "**Options**", select **Enabled Code Coverage** and save the build definition. *Note:No matter the Enabled Code Coverage option has been selected or not, you still need to save this edit.*

[image]

**Update**

---

You can specify the **test run setting file** which include the code coverage enabled to use in **Run Test Activities**.

[image]

Comment: I am not using the default template which has these setting, rather using UpgradeTemplate provided for using 2008 configuration path in VS 2013. I have added an RunTests Activity in this template to enable unit tests. But I am not able to see the test coverage result

Comment: You can specify the **test run setting file** which include the code coverage enabled to use in **Run Test Activities**. Please see my update.